# My Sites link in multisite is incorrect

Tags: multisite, admin-menu, network-admin

Within the network admin, the **My Sites** link, is not linking to the main parent site. Instead, it links to a child site blog. How can I change this link? Is there a way to rebuild WP menu? I haven't a clue how it became the wrong link.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by deactivating then reactivating the child site under Network Admin > Sites.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it occurred through the `switch_to_blog()` and `restore_current_blog()` functions in our theme. We called `restore_current_blog()` at the wrong position.

```php
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($posts as $post):
            switch_to_blog($post->blog_id); ?>
            <li><?php the_title();?></li>
            <?php restore_current_blog(); // correct position ?>
        <?php endforeach;?>
        <?php // restore_current_blog(); // wrong position ?>
    </ul>
```

We have to call `restore_current_blog()` each time in `forearch` syntax.